# Wordpress average RAM usage

Tags: wordpress, ram

On last few days, I'm facing some issues with Wordpress that simply uses too much memory(running on local network). Too much is an subjective word because the usage also depends on specifications of the web server. But because I couldn't find any information about average WP RAM usage, I want to ask about recomendations, any useful informations about this.

Comment: take a look at this: https://wordpress.org/plugins/server-ip-memory-usage/

Answer (score 0):

Most sites should have more than enough running at 128MB some run fine on less

you can change this by adding

```
define('WP_MEMORY_LIMIT', '128M');
```

to the wp-config.php file

Comment: I've already changed that to 64M (tried 128M before). Disabling plugins, testing it on few servers didn't work. Some more success was gained by changing permalink structure to **%post_id%** . But the customer isn't satisfied with it.

Comment: You could try a chache plugin to speed things up. That way every page will be cached as static .html file and will save a lot of time on loading plugins, database queryies & php.

zencache or quickcache are well known plugins for this.